# How can I modify with css an image appended with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have appended an image with JavaScript using a function that looked like this:

```
function show_image(src) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = src;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Now when I try modify its style in CSS:

```
    img{
     //style attributes etc.
}
```

The picture does not react. How can I fix this?

Comment: The styles WILL work. What is not working in your case?

Comment: After repaint the CSS properties are applied to the element in a normal browser. Inspect the element check it's styles.

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle or post the styles that you have added

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve the problem by using Class as suggested below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the CSS in javascript will help you to get solution:

add css in your function:

```
    function show_image(src) {
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = src;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
      $(document).find(img).css(here add your styles);
    }
```

example : $(your element).css("color", "red");

[REFERENCE](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_css.asp)

Answer (score -2):

There should be no problem with styles using css. However if they are giving you issues you could apply the style/class in javascript.

Comment: This isn't really helpful. It doesn't contribute any new information to the question

Answer (score -3):

Assign a className to that image

```
function show_image(src) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = src;
  img.className = "some-class-name";
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

And then in your CSS, write the selector as usual

```
.some-class-name {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: adding className does nothing better. The styles should work even without class.